# newly installed python3 using brew failing when I try to run pipenv install

Tags: homebrew, python

When I run pipenv i get the below error,

```
Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/python
  Reason: image not found
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python might help

Answer (score 1):

You can try below options:

- `brew install pipenv` # if you have brew installed
- `pip3 install pipenv` # if you don't have brew installed